# C# Agregar datos adjuntos a una base de datos en Access

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, ms-access

Tengo una base de datos en Access que tiene un campo de tipo 'Datos Ajuntos' y me gustaría insertar archivos pdf.

Tengo la ruta del PDF, sólo falta enviarlo. Imagino sería algo como:

```cs
//Abrimos la conexión mas arriba    
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(
    string.Format("INSERT INTO MONTAÑO (MONTAÑO.[CAMPO_ARCHIVO]) VALUES('" + archivo + "')
    ,conectado
);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//Cerramos la conexión aquí abajo
```

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta aclarando de qué tipo es `archivo` y cómo lo estás asignando?

Comment: Entiendo que el campo es Binario, prueba usando los parámetros de cmd, ya que es muy mala práctica la concatenación de valores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decidí migrar la base de Datos a sql Lite y usar campos binarios como me recomendaron y me va perfecto... 
Muchas Gracias no vuelvo a usar Acess se me hace insuficiente y algo lento en mi opinión personal :)